# Reacting on NFC Tags inside the android Framework itself

Tags: android, frameworks, android-activity, nfc, lockscreen

i'd like to recieve NFC Tags inside the android framework. Specifically inside the "LockPatternKeyguardView". The problem is that i'm not inside an activity context and therefor i can't recieve any intents from the NfcService. My idea so far is to have another activity react on all Nfc Tags and pass them via a BroadCast intent to a service running inside the "LockPatternKeyguardView".

Somehow i think this is not really a good way of doing it. Can anyone point out an alternative?

Thanks in advance,

Robert

Answer (score 0):

Since services cannot handle NFC intents, this sounds like a reasonable approach.